# How to trigger typescript recompilation within extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I develop a vscode extension and loaded a typescript plugin

Configure plugin via vscode

I need to tell typescript to recompile when the configuration changes

But it doesn't seem to find a way to trigger a recompilation

Is there any way to trigger typescript recompile in typescript-plugin or vscode?